# How to override sys.programGroup.linkDir?

Tags: install4j

In Windows, the Program Group name can be empty, so that I can assign the name programmatically.
But, the Symlinks directory field, cannot be left empty in "Create Program Group Action".
Is there any alternative?

btw, I am using 4.2.7 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set any installer variable like this:

```
context.setVariable("sys.programGroup.linkDir", "your value");
```